# What is this syntax of wrapping an enum type in parentheses?

Tags: c, enums

There's this really weird syntax that I don't understand. On the libcurl site documentation there's an enum defined as:

```
typedef enum {
  CURLSSLBACKEND_NONE = 0,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL = 1, /* or one of its forks */
  CURLSSLBACKEND_GNUTLS = 2,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_NSS = 3,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_GSKIT = 5, /* deprecated */
  CURLSSLBACKEND_POLARSSL = 6, /* deprecated */
  CURLSSLBACKEND_WOLFSSL = 7,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_SCHANNEL = 8,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_SECURETRANSPORT = 9,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_AXTLS = 10, /* deprecated */
  CURLSSLBACKEND_MBEDTLS = 11,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_MESALINK = 12, /* deprecated */
  CURLSSLBACKEND_BEARSSL = 13,
  CURLSSLBACKEND_RUSTLS = 14
} curl_sslbackend;
```

Then it calls a function called "curl_global_sslset() with the enum type wrapped in parentheses minus 1:

```
 /* list the available ones */
  const curl_ssl_backend **list;
  curl_global_sslset((curl_sslbackend)-1, NULL, &list);
```

This is really weird syntax to me, and I was surprised to find that:

```
int r = (curl_sslbackend) - 1;
```

Equals -1. But why? curl_sslbackend is a type, how can you use a minus operator on a type? What is happening here?

Comment: This is a cast. It casts `-1` to the type `curl_sslbackend`.

Comment: Declared like this the `enum` is just a fancy integer.

Comment: That's not a minus operator. It's a negative integer. Just like writing `x = -1`

Comment: Me, I'd have added a `CURLSSLBACKEND_UNSPECIFIED = -1` or something like that to the `enum` to keep the reading clean.

Comment: @user4581301 If you try to propose such change to curl vendors, your change will be closed with the reason: not motivated enough.

Comment: Not something I can help, I'm afraid. Besides, Yoda taught me not to try decades ago.

Comment: @273K I made PR [#11909](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/11909) to replace `(curl_sslbackend)-1` with `CURLSSLBACKEND_NONE` and it's been approved. This major improvement will be available in libcurl 8.4.0 :-)

Comment: @Ted You just proved Yoda wrong. That disturbance you feel is millions of voices suddenly crying out in terror and suddenly silenced.

Comment: @user4581301 :-D Darn! I only used the `git push --force` _once_ - promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put a type name in parentheses, it's a type cast. It means to convert the value after it to the specified type.

`-1` is not subtraction, it's a negative integer.

So

```
int r = (curl_sslbackend) -1;
```

means to convert the integer `-1` to the `curl_sslbackend` enum type, then assign this value to the integer `r`. So you're converting an integer to an enum, then converting the enum back to an integer. Which is basically a no-op, so it's the same as

```
int r = -1;
```

Comment: Oh my god, I saw a type minus 1, not negative 1 cast to type, oh gee.

Comment: I suspect you would not have been as confused if it were `(float)-1`